# EMC filter in DC-DC converter cascade

Tags: power-supply, power, dc-dc-converter

I'm designing a power supply stage and I have the cascade of multiple DC-DC converters. Each DC-DC converter has an EMC filter.

The first DC-DC converter requires a capacitor between Vout and GND C1 = 2uF, and the second DC-DC converter requires C2 = 47uF between Vin and GND. Since this is a cascade of DC-DC converters, C1 and C2 will be in parallel so there is an equivalent capacitance Ceq = C1+C2.

The problem is that Ceq is at the output of the first stage and at the input of the second stage, so there is a "conflict". How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen converter chip where required capacitance was specified as an exact number. It is always a range or at least a minimum. This goes for both input and output. So, in your case you have to figure out a number that a) satisfies both requirements from chip datasheets and b) sufficient for the ripple limit you set yourself.

Having said that, those large capacitors at the DC-DC inputs are usually decoupling, not EMC filters. The typical EMC filters for DC-DC converters are either LC or CLC and with much smaller capacitance.